# Wrong item order in ListBoxItem Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi, listbox, delphi-xe5, listboxitem

In my FireMonkey project create my own custom listboxItems with a TMemo, a TClearingEdit and a TCalendarEdit. When I add the items the order is correct but when I reload it the last 2 items are switched from position. Then if I add a new item the items switch back to the correct position.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Is this a firemonkey project? Please be more specific and show us some code.

Comment: Yes it is a firemonkey project. I updated my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a width to the listbox item